# LCM of first 20 natural numbers

Tags: c++, debugging

I have some code that is supposed to get me the LCM of first 20 natural numbers.

Here it is.

```
const bool IsPrime(const unsigned long long number) {
    cout<<"checking if "<<number<<" is prime.\n";
    //If a number cannot be divided by any number up to 
    //half of it, then that number is prime.
    for (unsigned long long i = 2; i<=number/2; ++i) {
        if (number%i==0) {
            cout<<number<<" is not prime.\n";
            return false;
        }
    }
    //the number seems to be prime.
    cout<<number<<" is PRIME.\n";
    return true;
}

vector<int> PrimeFactorize(int number) {
    cout<<"Prime factorizing "<<number<<"\n";
    vector<int> prime_factors;
    for (int num = 2; !IsPrime(number); ++num) {
        if (number%num==0&&IsPrime(num)) {
            cout<<number<<" is divisible by "<<num<<" and "<<num<<" is PRIME.\n";
            number /= num;
            prime_factors.push_back(num);
            num = 1;
        }
    }
    prime_factors.push_back(number);
    return prime_factors;
 }

void Problem5( ) {
    vector<int> prime_factors[19];
    int max_prime_powers[19] = {0};
    //prime factorize all the numbers.
    for (int i = 2; i<=20; ++i) {
        prime_factors[i-2] = PrimeFactorize(i);
        int temp_max_powers[19] = {0};

    for (auto& prime_factor:prime_factors[i-2]) {
        ++temp_max_powers[prime_factor];
    }

    //compare powers obtained and update the
    //max_prime_factors
    for (int u = 0; u<19; ++u) {
        if (max_prime_powers[u]<temp_max_powers[u]) {
            max_prime_powers[u] = temp_max_powers[u];
        }
    }
}

//now multiply all the things together to get the lcm.
int LCM=1;
for (int y = 2; y<19; ++y) {
    LCM *= (y^(max_prime_powers[y]));
}

cout<<"\n\n\n the answer is "<<LCM<<"\n";

}
```

I tried stepping through it, it does what it should do until i reach the last loop where i multiply all the primes with powers to get the lcm. Thecalculation doesn't work as expected. It does the calculation wrongly even though the code shows the right thing.

After the function returns, I get a runtime error saying

```
Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'temp_max_powers' was corrupted.
```

What is the matter? how does temp_max_powers corrupt the stack?

I am using visual studio professional 13. Is this a compiler bug?

**UPDATE** 
According to the comment, I corrected the code there instead of

```
LCM *= (y^(max_prime_powers[y]));
```

I now have

```
LCM *= _Pow_int(y,(max_prime_powers[y]));
```

this doesn't give me the right answer, and the error still pops up.

Comment: The `^` operator does not mean what you want. (See ["Bitwise Exclusive OR Operator: ^" on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3akey979.aspx).)

Comment: So there isn't an exponent operator in c++?

Comment: Nope. There's a standard-library function `pow` (see ["pow, powf, powl" on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dt5dakze.aspx)), but that's for floating-point values -- it works using logarithms and exponentiation -- so it's not the best way to compute small powers of integers.

Comment: The algorithms are a bit strange. To factorize, you don't need to reset num to 1, just to num-1, and you don't need to check that num is prime, it has to be. Also, you don't need to factorize to compute the lcm, only test for primality (sieve?). Just list all primes smaller than 20, and for each of them, find the max power that appears before 20. For 2, 16<=20<32 so keep 16. For 3, 9<=20<27 so keep 9. Then 5, 7, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Problem 1**

```
LCM *= (y^(max_prime_powers[y]));
```

`a^b` is not used for a<sup>b</sup> in C++/

**Problem 2**

Choice of int for LCM for 20 numbers may not be a good choice as it may overflow.

**Problem 3**

```
for (auto& prime_factor:prime_factors[i-2]) {
    ++temp_max_powers[prime_factor];
}
```

Here you should debug by printing the value of `prime_factor`, it may `19` or more which causes UB. (stack corruption for example)

Instead of `int temp_max_powers[19]`, you should use `std::map<int, int> temp_max_powers`

**A better algorithm to calculate LCM**
If you can ensure there is no integer overflow during multiplication, you can use the below observations to calculate LCM.

1. `LCM(a, b) = a * b / GCD(a, b)` // You can calculate GCD quickly using [euclidean method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm#Implementations)
2. `LCM(a1, a2, a3, ... an) = LCM(a1, LCM(a2, a3, ... an))`

Comment: changing the type of LCM from int to long long int still doesn't solve the problem...

Comment: Check problem 3 also. Moreover changing from `int` to `long long` would just push the problem and not completely eliminate it.